# Python Flask app not exiting with sys exit

Tags: python, flask

I'd like to be able to terminate my flask app remotely with an http request like this:

```
import flask
import sys

master = flask.Flask(__name__)

@master.route('/shutdown')
def shutdown():
    #do things
    sys.exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    master.run()
```

Thing is it just doesn't work. From the terminal I get nothing, as if it's not even processing the request. I know that sys.exit() just raises a SystemExit, so I think it may be that it gets caught somewhere. The fact that os._exit(0) does work also leads me to think so.

Am I tripping on something stupid? Is it actually a bug and there is a workaround? I'd prefer not to use os._exit(0) if possible. Thanks!

Edit: I wouldn't say this question is a duplicate since the accepted answers differ and the other one is from '13 (Flask's gone a long way in the meantime)

Comment: This seems relevant: [How to stop flask application without using ctrl-c](//stackoverflow.com/q/15562446)

Comment: So what if “the accepted answers differ”? Do any of them solve you problem? If not, tell us why not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's no bug.

As flask is probably catching all exceptions in order to do not stop the main process from serving the application.

As you mention, using os._exit(0) does the work.

As far as I've seen, it's catched by python2.7/SocketServer.py:

```
598         try:
599             self.finish_request(request, client_address)
600             self.shutdown_request(request)
601         except:
602             self.handle_error(request, client_address)
603             self.shutdown_request(request)
```

Which basically catches everything but handles an error.

BTW: Am I the only one who thinks that this could be refactored with a try/except/finally?

Comment: Thank you, yes that bare try/except isn't optimal. I believe I'll stick to os._exit then ;)

Comment: Just note that if your application is on production environment and running under gunicorn. It will be useless ;)