# How to exit a python script called in a Flask app?

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I have a flask app where I am reusing a function in a python script (poll_servers.py). I can import the function and run it but I want to put a check in place that exits the function if it's running.

Here is my code in the python script:

```
import os
import sys

# check if lock file exists, exit
if os.path.exists('static/poll.lock'):
    sys.exit(1)

if not os.path.exists('static/poll.lock'):
    with open('static/poll.lock', 'w'): pass
```

In my app.py I have:

```
from poll_servers import poll

@app.route('/poll_servers', methods=['GET'])
def poll_servers():

    response = json.dumps({'status':'OK'})

    poll()

    return response
```

I get an error on the `sys.exit(1)` in poll_servers.py:

```
File "app.py", line 109, in poll_servers
  poll()
File ".../poll_servers.py", line 262, in poll
  sys.exit(1)
File ".../venv/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 403, in __call__
  raise SystemExit(code)
SystemExit: None
```

Any ideas? If I run the poll_servers.py on its own the `sys.exit(1)` works fine.

Comment: Which error is thrown?

Comment: Works fine for me if I change `static/poll.lock` to `/tmp/poll.lock`.

Comment: I added the error. Still throws an exception when moving the lock file to the `tmp` directory as suggested.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52427999/python-flask-app-not-exiting-with-sys-exit

Comment: The file can stay in `static`, this won't change anything. I just used a different path.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Flask app not exiting with sys exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52427999/python-flask-app-not-exiting-with-sys-exit)

Comment: I don't want Flask to exit, I just need the imported function `poll` to stop executing if a lock file is found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then just don't do anything or flip the order of your `if` statement:

```
import os
import sys

if not os.path.exists('static/poll.lock'):

    with open('static/poll.lock', 'w'): 

        pass

else:

    pass
    # do something
```